# Global json serialization option in .Net Core 3.x

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I have .Net Core 3.1 Web Api. I am using `System.Text.Json` serializer since it became a default for .Net Core 3.x applications. I have set global enum to string converter as follows:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter())));
        ... 
    }
```

Enums are converted to string for controller responses (which makes sense since I configure on `AddControllers()` method). But if I try to manually serialize an object it still serializes enum as int. Sample below:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyObject { Enum1 = MyEnum.Value1, Enum2 = MyEnum.Value2 });
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public MyEnum Enum1 { get; set; }
        public MyEnum Enum2 { get; set; }
    }

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Value1 = 1,
        Value2 = 2
    }   
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
data [string]: "{\"Enum1\":1,\"Enum2\":2}"
```

If I add conversion attribute manually then it serializes as desired:

```
    public class MyObject
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
        public MyEnum Enum1 { get; set; }
        public MyEnum Enum2 { get; set; }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
data [string]: "{\"Enum1\":\"Value1\",\"Enum2\":2}"
```

Is there a way to set global json serialization options (enum to string conversion) that would apply for manual serialization as well?

Or maybe I should just always stick to the explicit attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't. `JsonSerializer` being a static class with only purely static methods, default options cannot be set. You can check this [open issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094). It seems that it has been designed this way for better performance.

As an alternative, you can create your own static class

```cs
public static class CustomJsonSerializer
{
    private static JsonSerializerOptions serializerSettings =
        new JsonSerializerOptions { /* whatever you need */};

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string json)
    {       
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, serializerSettings );
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I managed to get this to work by adding `NewtonsoftJson` and then register `StringEnumConverter`:

```
services
.AddControllers(jsonOptions => jsonOptions.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true)
.AddNewtonsoftJson(jsonOptions =>
                 {
                     jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add((JsonConverter) new StringEnumConverter());
                 }
```

Comment: I am getting following error out of your example: `Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter' to 'System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter'`. And I don't understand how it could work. Can you just simple cast one coverter to another?